# WordPress Php signature script hide

Tags: php, wordpress

[Serverental](http://www.serverental.com) Website is too slow. How can we improve the website performance? Also the website server signature is visible and I would like to hide it. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

For faster results there are many aspects are working behind it. 
Like,
1) Server execution time
2) May or may not be followed the coding stands (generally it will be the main reason for the slower site.)

P.S. Can not get your second question about the Server Signature ... if possible please explain with image so that it would be easy to understand.